# Allow user to add items to spinner in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, kotlin, spinner, edit

I have a spinner where the contents are from an Array in Strings.xml. However I would like to be able to let the user add items to the array. Can anyone help and let me know if there is a way to do this?

Many thanks

Comment: Thank you, not sure yet, I am looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayAdapter` has a method `add(object)` as seen here: [ArrayAdapter | Android Developer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter)

For example:

```
fun addItem(item: T) {
    arrayAdapter.add(item)

    // Refreshes the view to reflect the changes applied to arrayAdapter
    arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()  
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I will have a look and see if I can get this to work!